# Two text divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have two divs-one for content text and one for title of this text.

```
///////////////////
/ ........        /
/ .      .  .  .  /
/ .div1  .  . 2.  /
/ ........        /
///////////////////
```

The second div should stay in the center of the div1's height and positioned absolute on the right side.

[how should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi8Zv.png)

The div's 2 content also is rotated on 90degree.

Note: `.textFull` is the main content text div and the `div.tit` is the second title div.

```
.textFull{
    float:left;
        z-index:15;
       display:block;
         font-size: calc(2vh + 2vw);
       margin-top:100vh;
        width:80vw;
        background-color: #141414;
        color:white;
     opacity:0.7;
border-top-right-radius:0.2em;
border-bottom-right-radius:0.2em;
padding:1vw;
    }
    div.tit{
    position:absolute;
 z-index:15;
       transform:rotate(90deg);
         font-size: calc(2vh + 2vw);
      float:right;
        top:120vh;
        background-color: #141414;
        color:white;
     opacity:0.7;

right:0;
    }
```

[How it looks like in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PpmY.jpg)

Here is the html:

```
<body id='random'>
<div id='an'></div>
<h1 id='header'>Hi. I'm Atanas Bobev</h1>
<div class='textFull'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque volutpat aliquam enim at porttitor. Aenean nec turpis ipsum. Donec egestas pharetra tellus id scelerisque. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam ornare arcu sit amet massa finibus lacinia. Maecenas sed magna metus. Pellentesque id lectus libero. Donec semper est magna, efficitur varius ipsum ultricies eleifend. Maecenas non dictum tellus, sed vulputate erat. Proin sed pharetra augue.</div>
```

```js
  
  randombg();
  const maxFiles = 159;
const randomEl = document.getElementById("random");
function randombg() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxFiles)+1;
  randomEl.style.backgroundImage = `url('image/(${random}).jpeg')`;

}
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#header').typewrite({
   blinkingCursor:false,
   selectedBackground:"#141414",
   selectedText:"#ffffff",
                actions: [
     {delay: 1000},
                    {type: 'Hello.'},
     {delay: 1000},
     {remove: {num: 6, type: 'stepped'}},
                   
      {delay: 1000},
                    {type: "I'm Atanas Bobev"},
      {delay: 1000},
     {remove: {num: 12, type: 'stepped'}},
      {delay: 1000},
       {type: "31 years old."},
        {delay: 1000},
       {remove: {num: 13, type: 'stepped'}},
        {delay: 1000},
        {type: "web designer."},
     {select: {from: 26, to: 47}}
                ]
            });
        });
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:TypeFont;
    src: url(fonts/Lobster-Regular.ttf);
}
*{margin:0;padding:0;transition:1s;font-family:TypeFont;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;}
html,head,body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
        

}
#an{
    position:fixed;
background: linear-gradient(229deg, #a1c4fd, #c2e9fb, #cfd9df, #667eea, #764ba2, #e2d1c3, #89f7fe, #66a6ff, #48c6ef, #6f86d6, #feada6, #a3bded, #6991c7, #13547a, #80d0c7, #93a5cf, #434343, #000000, #93a5cf, #ff758c, #868f96, #596164, #c79081, #dfa579, #09203f, #96deda, #50c9c3, #29323c, #485563, #1e3c72, #2a5298, #b7f8db, #50a7c2, #2193b0, #6dd5ed);
    background-size: 7400% 7400%;
    animation: backgroundGardient 400s ease infinite;
z-index:-10;
opacity:0.5;
width:99vw;
height:100%;
-webkit-animation: backgroundGardient 400s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: backgroundGardient 400s ease infinite;
-o-animation: backgroundGardient 400s ease infinite;
animation: backgroundGardient 400s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundGardient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 83%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 18%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 83%
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes backgroundGardient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 83%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 18%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 83%
    }
}
@-o-keyframes backgroundGardient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 83%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 18%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 83%
    }
}
@keyframes backgroundGardient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 83%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 18%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 83%
    }
}
#jquery-script-menu {
position: fixed;
height: 90px;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-top: 5px solid #316594;
background: #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);

padding: 10px 0;
-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
-moz-box-sizing:content-box;
box-sizing:content-box;
}

.jquery-script-center {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.jquery-script-center ul {
width: 212px;
float:left;
line-height:45px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}
.jquery-script-center a {
 text-decoration:none;
}
.jquery-script-ads {
width: 728px;
height:90px;
float:right;
}
.jquery-script-clear {
clear:both;
height:0;
}
#random{
position:fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;  
    background-size:cover;                     
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;    
 
  font-size:calc(1vh + 1vw);
  
}
#header > span.blinkingCursor{
display:none;
}

h1#header{

    
 position: absolute;

  top: 50%;
               left: 50%;
               -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
               transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
               background-color: #ecf0f1;
               color: black;
               opacity: 0.7;
               -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
               border: 20px solid #ecf0f1;
               font-size: calc(2vh + 2vw + 1vmax + 0.5em);
               font-weight: 100;
               box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);


    
      }
    .textFull{
 float:left;
        z-index:15;
       display:block;
         font-size: calc(2vh + 2vw);
       margin-top:100vh;
        width:80vw;
        background-color: #141414;
  color:white;
     opacity:0.7;
border-top-right-radius:0.2em;
border-bottom-right-radius:0.2em;
padding:1vw;
    }
 div.tit{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:15;
       transform:rotate(90deg);
         font-size: calc(2vh + 2vw);
      float:right;
        top:120vh;
        background-color: #141414;
  color:white;
     opacity:0.7;

right:0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/typeout.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/typewrite.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/typewrite.js"></script>
  
  
<head>

<style>

</style>

</head>
<body id='random'>
<div id='an'></div>
<h1 id='header'>Hi. I'm Atanas Bobev</h1>
<div class='textFull'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque volutpat aliquam enim at porttitor. Aenean nec turpis ipsum. Donec egestas pharetra tellus id scelerisque. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam ornare arcu sit amet massa finibus lacinia. Maecenas sed magna metus. Pellentesque id lectus libero. Donec semper est magna, efficitur varius ipsum ultricies eleifend. Maecenas non dictum tellus, sed vulputate erat. Proin sed pharetra augue.</div>
<div class='tit'>Who i am?</div>
<script>


  
  
  
  
  
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<div class='tit'>Who i am?</div>
```

*I know there is js errors because of file missing

Comment: You forgot your HTML in the question. Please edit your question and create a complete and working example you can use the `<>` button in the editor. Side note: Your indents are the worst I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't use all your code because I do not get what it is about but I have shared the containers and layout you could use to achieve what you want.

```css
.inflex {
  display: flex;
  /*Center the items in the div.inflex*/
  align-items: center;
  background: #dc3;
}

.textFull {
  flex-basis: 90%;
  background: #ba3;
}

.tit {
  flex: 1;
  /*Center the items in the div using flex*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/*Rotate the content to 90 deg*/
.tit > div {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  text-align: center;
  background: #a03;
}
```

```html
<body id='random'>
  <div id='an'></div>
  <h1 id='header'>Hi. I'm Atanas Bobev</h1>
  <!--Added the div.inflex so I can use flexbox to put the boxes side by side and center the content-->
  <div class="inflex">
  <div class='textFull'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque volutpat aliquam enim at porttitor. Aenean nec turpis ipsum. Donec egestas pharetra tellus id scelerisque. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam ornare arcu sit amet massa finibus lacinia. Maecenas sed magna metus. Pellentesque id lectus libero. Donec semper est magna, efficitur varius ipsum ultricies eleifend. Maecenas non dictum tellus, sed vulputate erat. Proin sed pharetra augue.</div>
    <div class='tit'>
      <div>Who i am?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```